# View the php script of any site with browser

Tags: javascript, php, forms, sql-injection

I'm trying to hack a riddle like game on a website where we enter the correct answer and proceed to next level. In the source I've found the form is defined as `<form id="submission-form" class="row" action="#" name="subForm">`
and the following script

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){e.preventDefault();submitAnswer();});
```

I tried to find the definition of `submitAnswer()` function but couldn't find any in all the scripts. And When I submit the form my browser makes a post request to the php file which is mentioned in the page url also.
So my questions are

1. Is the `submitAnswer` a php function and if not is there any way to find its definition?
2. Can I view the php script that the form is posting to anyhow.
3. This one is lame , Is there any way I can extract the correct answer from the server(by sql injection or some tool) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `submitAnswer()` is a Javascript function and is there somewhere, if you look hard enough.
2. No.
3. Probably not, depending on the proficiency of the programmer who setup the PHP code.

Comment: I suppose it's also possible that #1 is a red herring.

Comment: I would agree with that @j08691

Comment: The Javascript code could be obfuscated, so you can't search for the function name directly.